# How do I access an element with custom name in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to click on  element, but watir gives me an error, saying - undefined method `small' for #

```
<li class="lastMove">
<div id="81ae2" class="folder">
<i onclick="someFunction1()">
<small onclick="someFunction2()"> </small>
</span>
</div>
</li>
```

What are the possible solutions for getting a custom element?

Answer (score 2):

To find a custom element, you will need to use the generic `element` method with a css or xpath locator.

Using a css-locator:

```
browser.element(:css => 'small').click
```

Using xpath:

```
browser.element(:xpath=> '//small').click
```

You could also use the :tag_name as a locator, however it will differ between watir-classic and watir-webdriver. Watir-classic requires an array while webdriver requires a string.

```
browser.element(:tag_name => 'small').click # in watir-webdriver
browser.element(:tag_name => ['small']).click # in watir-classic
```

Comment: Could you give me a documentation link for the same? Where I can get to see some examples of such things.

Comment: @Babai, I do not know of this being documented anywhere (though I could put it in my future book). It is a bit of an edge case to do this, so I think it is something you just pick up after years of using Watir.

Comment: Okay,you are writing any book.. Any reference so that I can read it.

Comment: @Babai, you could read my [blog](http://jkotests.wordpress.com). I try to create a post for the various problems I solve. Conceptually my book is really just a structured version of my blog with some extra details. If you want to know when the book is published you could follow it on [leanpub](https://leanpub.com/watirways). Though it may just get merged into the [watir book](https://leanpub.com/watirbook).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will definitely get that one!

Comment: After executing `element(:xpath=> '//small').click` it says  `undefined method `element_by_xpath`. I am using watir 2.0.2

Comment: Odd. I do not get that problem (when using watir 2.0.2). Can you find anything by xpath (eg a standard element type)? Does the css approach at least work? It looks like the tag_name will not work in 2.0.2.

Comment: Justin Ko - can you open up an issue for the difference of using `tag_name` in `watir-classic`? This should not definitely be like that.

Comment: [Issue 62](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/issues/62) has been created for watir-classic.